# System.Reflection.Еmit is not supported unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

подскажите, может кто сталкивался.
При переходе на 2017.2.0f3 версию и билдах под iOS ( .NET 4.6 & IL2CPP сборка ), XMLSerializer ругается на System.Reflection.Emit , тобишь typeOf(T) при ините сериалайзера невозможно сделать. Кто-то как-то обходил это или же, просто сменить сериализацию на newtonesoft JSON ( говорят,что System.Reflection.Emit на IL2CPP поддерживается там( пока не пробовал ).

Comment: не работает Emit на AOT компиляторах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос старый, но хотел бы уточнить кое-какие моменты.

1. IL2CPP платформы не поддерживают генерацию с помощью `System.Reflection.Emit`. Это WebGL, iOS и почти все консоли.
2. Newtonesoft JSON - хорошее решение. В [форке для Unity3d](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D) не используется `System.Reflection.Emit`, так что оно будет работать везде. Единственное, там иногда из-за `StrippingLevel` могут некоторые классы из билда вылететь. Но для этого есть `link.xml`, где вы можете указать, какие классы принудительно стоит оставить в сборке.